# Why does the image flicker when displayed?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am making a clock in my game. After roughly 60 seconds it changes to the next number. I use the subroutine below to change the clock image when it needs to. My problem is that the images flickers when displayed, and I don't want that.

My code;

```
def display_night_clock():  
    global var_clock
    global var_6_am
    
    if var_hide == False:
        if var_6_am == False:
            if var_clock == 1:
                screen.blit(image_12_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 2:
                screen.blit(image_1_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 3:
                screen.blit(image_2_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 4:
                screen.blit(image_3_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 5:
                screen.blit(image_4_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 6:
                screen.blit(image_5_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
            if var_clock == 7:
                screen.blit(image_7_am, (1266, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
                var_6_am = True
                var_clock = 1
```

I just call this subroutine in my main loop. I have used this method of displaying images before in my program in my other subroutines, and those images don't flicker. But for some reason these images flicker.

Comment: You're calling `pygame.display.update()` in this method, I suspect you are calling `pygame.display.update()` multiple times per frame/game loop and this is updating the display when you don't want it to? You should only call this once per frame/loop and probably outside of any function other than your main game loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by multiple calls to [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update). An update of the display at the end of the application loop is sufficient. Multiple calls to `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` cause flickering.

Remove all calls to `pygame.display.update()` from your code, but call it once at the end of the application loop:

```py
while running:
   # [...] 

   pygame.display.update()
```